# Dfmcheck checks subcomponents of FastReport that are not declared in unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, fastreport

I'm working on a XE3 project which uses FastReport design for reporting.

When i try to run DFMCheck the generated unit tries to access the subcomponents of the report (i.e. TfrxDataPage) which are present in the .DFM but are not created in the classdefinition of the form. If i try to add the fields to the form declaration in the .PAS file, Delhi tells me that it does not have a corresponding component and asks me to delete the declaration.

So the .dfm looks like this:

```
  object frxReport1: TfrxReport
  ...
    object Data: TfrxDataPage
      Height = 1000.000000000000000000
      Width = 1000.000000000000000000
    end
```

The .pas looks like this:

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  frxReport1: TfrxReport;
  Data: TfrxDataPage;  // Added manually, but gets deleted when saving the form
  ...
```

The DfmCheck_Unit generated by DFMCheck contains this:

```
  with TMyForm(nil) do { uForm2.pas }
  begin
    frxReport1.ClassName; { frxReport1: TfrxReport; }
    Data.ClassName; { Data: TfrxDataPage; }
    ..
```

The Data.Classname statement generates a compile error because the Data component is not declared.

How do I get DFMCheck to accept this and not generate the teststaments for subcomponents of TfrxReport anymore?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Andy about this issue? You can use his webpage as a starting point: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2016/01/dfmcheck-1-6-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DFMCheck doesn't know the component classes. It only looks at the DFM and sees  `object` what means that the `Data: TfrxDataPage` component is part of the Form/Frame/Datamodule. It can't know that FastReport created a sub-component without an accessible field.

The only way to solve this would be black-listing those components, what DFMCheck doesn't support (yet?).